# Simplifying JSON entries in Python

Tags: python, json, xml

I'm currently working on converting a large XML file into JSON. I've managed to parse the XML file using xmltodict, but the resulting output is a bit messy and could do with some cleaning up. The output currently looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "att": "id",
        "val": "90552",
        "feat": [
            {
                "att": "homonym_number",
                "val": "0"
            },
            {
                "att": "lexicalUnit",
                "val": "단어"
            },
            {
                "att": "partOfSpeech",
                "val": "명사"
            },
            {
                "att": "origin",
                "val": "讓渡稅"
            },
            {
                "att": "vocabularyLevel",
                "val": "없음"
            }
        ],
        "Lemma": {
            "feat": {
                "att": "writtenForm",
                "val": "양도세"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I'm hoping to strip out the "feat", "att", and "val" tags to get to something like this:

```
[
    {
        "att": "id",
        "val": "90552",
        "homonym_number": "0",
        "lexicalUnit": "단어",
        "partOfSpeech": "명사",
        "origin": "讓渡稅",
        "vocabularyLevel": "없음",
        "Lemma": {
            "writtenForm": "양도세"
        }
    }
]
```

I was considering reading all of the "feat" wrapped data into lists and then writing a new JSON file, but would there be a quicker way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a quicker way. You need to write XML parser using `[xml.etree.ElementTree][1]` for example instead of xmltodict.

Alternatively, you could pass the item_callback function to the xmltodict. parse and to do postprocessing and output for each object.